# swagger-ui auto replaces escaped characters like ""

Tags: vb.net, swagger

Basically I am using .Net VB to pass in a JSON String format into Swagger-UI for Response Body.
But the Response Body displays characters like "\" 
I want to get rid of that.

my Json string looks something like this in VB

```
sJSON = "{""csid"":""" + customer.CSID.ToString() + """}"
```

The Current Result is:

{\"csid\":\"1234\"}

Desired Result is:

{"csid":"1234"}

> New Edits:

The string is generated from my custom print JSON class
It's the default method that came with the Controller class I mimic from HomeControllers.
I am guessing it needs to set the "application/JSON" content type?

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
   Return PrintJSON()
End Function

Function PrintJSON()

        Dim sJSON As String
        ' Begin JSON object
        sJSON = "{"

        ' Timestamp
        sJSON = sJSON + """date"":""" + DateTime.Today().ToShortDateString + ""","
        sJSON = sJSON + """time"":""" + DateTime.Today().ToShortTimeString + ""","

        ' Return list of parameters in a JSON object
        sJSON = sJSON + ""
        sJSON = sJSON + """record"":["

        For Each customer In Customers
            sJSON = sJSON + "{"
            sJSON = sJSON + """csid"":""" + customer.CSID.ToString() + """"
            sJSON = sJSON + "}"

            If customer.Equals(Customers.Last) Then
                sJSON = sJSON + "]"
            Else
                sJSON = sJSON + ","
            End If
        Next


        sJSON = sJSON + "}"

        Return sJSON
    End Function
```

Comment: How is this string used exactly? Is it sent as the HTTP response body? If yes, post the full code that sends the response. Or is it part of your API definition (Swagger JSON/YAML file)? The more details, the easier it will be for someone to help you.

Comment: The string is generated from 
`Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String`

It's the default method that came with the Controller class I mimic from HomeControllers.

The String is returned from a separate method

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.  The GetValue method can just return a data transfer object class.

Swagger will automatically display the class in JSON format.

I sure hope this was explained clearer in the Swagger tutorial.